# To extend axes limits with custom axis tick labels in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization, axes

I am trying to set my plot with custom axis tick labels and I want my x-axis, y-axis limit range to be same. In the image the y-axis maximum value is 31622776 and I want to extend the y-axis to 100000000 (same as x-axis). The code I used is

```
ax = sns.scatterplot(x="Actual", y="Predict",hue="Flag",style="Flag",data=df)
x_labels = {31622 : 4.5 , 100000 : 5 ,316227 : 5.5 ,1000000 : 6 ,3162277 : 6.5 ,10000000 : 7 ,31622776 : 7.5, 100000000 : 8}     
ax.set_xticklabels(x_labels)
y_labels = {31622 : 4.5 , 100000 : 5 ,316227 : 5.5 ,1000000 : 6 ,3162277 : 6.5 ,10000000 : 7 ,31622776 : 7.5 , 100000000 : 8}
ax.set_yticklabels(y_labels)
plt.title(r'Log-Log plot of Actual Sales Price Vs Predicted Sales Price')
plt.xlabel(r'Actual Sales Price in Dollars')
plt.ylabel(r'Predicted Sales Price in Dollars')
```

[image]

I am confused about what change I should make to achieve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use matplotlib.pyplot.xlim() / .ylim() in addition to setting tick labels. Tick labels won't automatically change the axis scaling.

See: https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xlim.html